# How to determine which row has changed/updated on Google Sheets Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets, onchange, google-apps-script-editor

For my google sheets, each row gets populated at random, but when it does get populated, I want a function to run. Each time something gets populated, it's the next row (it's not a cell or a random row).

I have the onChange trigger running right now. It is set to "run FunctionA from Spreadsheet on change". In that function, how do I grab the row that has been specifically changed/updated? What is the function/method I would use to manipulate whatever that row is?

I searched around but couldn't find an appropriate answer.

Comment: "I have the onChange trigger running right now." Why don't you do it in your on change function?

Comment: So in my trigger, it is set to "run functionA from spreadsheet on change", but in that functionA, I was wondering how I can grab the specific row that has been changed. Sorry if my question is unclear! I'll update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `onEdit` spreadsheet event. (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

You can call it this way :

```
function onEdit(e){
    //Access the range with your parameter e.
    var range = e.range;
    var row = range.getRow();
    var column = range.getColumn();
    //do whatever you need with that range
}
```

It will automatically run when there is an edit on a cell of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Will it only run if any cell gets updated? Or is there a way to make it so it'll run only when a row in the spreadsheet gets updated?

Comment: It only runs on cells, but when a row is updated the cells are too so the function will run

Comment: This is exactly what I need then. So I would modify my trigger to run the function called onEdit(e) on my spreadsheet when there's an edit?

Comment: You don't need a trigger, if the name of the function is onEdit it will automatically run without you needing to anything when there is an edit.

Comment: Oh wow. That's amazing! I'll use this then. But if you don't mind, can you explain to me why there are triggers then? What's the point of a trigger if you can just use this onEdit functionality?

Comment: Well triggers are use to run a task at a precise time/interval. For example, you could need to run a script every day to change values on your spreadsheet, or check if value have changed.