# Writing a google sheets function to only apply to changed rows

Tags: google-sheets, twilio, twilio-api, google-apps-script-editor

I've recently integrated Twilio with one of my sheets to automatically send messages to phone numbers. An example process is below...

1. Spreadsheet contains several hundred rows with specific message details in each that twilio sends to a specific phone number
2. Function is set to trigger on sheet edit
3. User enters a phone number in rows 3, 59, and 148 that have the unique message details to send
4. Function triggers and sends messages

The problem is that the function I have will search the entire sheet for a phone number. I would like to write the function so it immediately knows which cells have been edited (with the new phone number) and only runs the function on those rows. So instead of taking 30 minutes to comb through every row looking for a phone number, it only looks at those rows that changed.

Any idea how I can make this happen? The function I have so far is below. I know the line I need to change, but just dont know the code to put.

```html
function sendSms(to, body) {
var messages_url = "INSERT TWILIO URL HERE";
var payload = {
"To": to,
"Body" : body,
"From" : "(315) 888-4032"
};
var options = {
"method" : "post",
"payload" : payload
};
options.headers = {
"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("PRIVATE INFO")
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}
function sendAll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
try {
response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
status = "sent";
} catch(err) {
Logger.log(err);
status = "error";
}
sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 3).setValue(status);
}
}
function myFunction() {
sendAll();
}
```

Comment: Does the `onEdit` event help you with this at all? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587028/how-to-determine-which-row-has-changed-updated-on-google-sheets-script-editor

Comment: @philnash so there might be way to use the result of that function from the link you sent as the range? so right now, I have

function sendAll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
var data = dataRange.getValues();

but maybe there's a way to insert the other function into that? I dont know...

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to dig more into this myself. I'd have a look at the `event` object's `range` properties, which shows you all of the cells that have been edited. You could then check within that range for a phone number and decide whether to run your function to send messages.